# Select a cataloging / metadata system?

Tags: software-recommendations, metadata, catalog-service

We are setting up a GIS server based on QGIS / PostgreSQL-PostGIS and GeoServer.
We are missing an important tool, the cataloging and metadata system.

PostgreSQL and GeoServer are on a Windows Server 2019 virtual server.

We are GIS & geomatics people but not computer scientists. We are therefore looking for an opensource solution that is relatively easy to install and configure, which does not require extensive computer skills.

What solutions do you think would be suitable?

We have identified :

1. Geonetwork,
2. Georchestra https://www.georchestra.org/software.html
3. Geonode

Are there others?

Among these 3 solutions, would there be one easier to set and use, which would be functional on both Linux and Windows?

Are there other criteria to take into account in our selection of technology?

Comment: The [softwarerecs.se] exchange exists for software recommendations, so that's going to be a better fit than asking for opinions with a list of questions in GIS SE.

Comment: Before you invest too much time I would strongly recommend you talk to your audience as some people like geonetwork and some like the look of geonode and you want to engage with as many people as you can instead of becoming yet another data portal...

Comment: Are you wanting to have your metadata conform to any standards, how do you want write or create your metadata? how do you want to provide access to your metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going toward the Web world, you definitely want to have a closer look at the [STAC](https://stacspec.org/) API today.
This API is aligned with the [OGC API - Features](https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/) (a.k.a. WFS3) and it also relies on the OpenAPI standard.
It's especially suited for cataloging large spatio-temporal datasets, but depending on your background, there will of course be a learning curve.

> (...)
> The philosophy of STAC is to focus on making it as easy as possible for data providers to expose their data to the world. Most geospatial catalogs require the provider of data to maintain servers and databases to enable search. This can be a large challenge with huge amounts of data. STAC aims to flip that paradigm on its head, following the path of the web, where putting up an HTML page is very simple, and then the search of those pages can be done by anyone, with experts in search emerging over time. STAC aims to enable that next generation of geospatial search engines, while also supporting web best practices so geospatial information is more easily surfaced in traditional search engines.
> (...)

https://stacspec.org/overview.html
https://stacspec.org/STAC-api.html

More on the core features:  https://stacspec.org/core.html
Specs are on Github: https://github.com/radiantearth/stac-spec
The STAC index: https://stacindex.org/

Directly related to the OGC API - Features, you can also have a look to:

- this Python framework: https://www.osgeo.org/projects/pygeoapi/
- QGIS (server), which is also pushing toward the usage of this RESTful API: https://blog.qgis.org/2020/05/13/qgis-server-and-ogc-api-features/